# Confused about R terminology: Attributes, parameters, and arguments

Tags: r, function, parameters, attributes, arguments

Once and for all I want to get the R terminology right. However, none of the books I was reading was of big help, and it seems to me the authors choose the names sometimes arbitrarily. So, my question is when exactly are the names "attribute", "parameter", and "argument" used?

From what I read and understood so far, a parameter is what a function can take as input. For example if I have a function that calculates the sum of two values, `sum(value1, value2)`, 'value1' and 'value2' are the function's parameters.

If we are calling a function, we call the values passed to the function arguments. For the sum-function example, "23" and "48" would be the function arguments for:

```
sum(23,48).
```

So basically we call it parameter when we define a function, and we call it argument when we call the function (so the arguments are passed to the function's parameters)

But what about "attributes"? From what I understand, attributes are the equivalent of parameters in methods (and methods are functions of a class object)?

For example, if I would have something like:

```
heatmap(myData, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA)
```

... , would 'myData' be an argument or attribute? And what about `Colv=NA` and `Rowv=NA`? Isn't heatmap() a function and thus everything in the parentheses should be called arguments?

Comment: There is no consistency in the use of these terms between authors.

Comment: I think this was what was so confusing to me. I just want to know when I should use which if I am writing about those things so it makes sense to people

Comment: This ought not to have been closed.  Actual and formal arguments are objectively the names given for the concepts here and its not true that the question is not constructive nor is it particularly argumentative.  I am voting to reopen it.

Comment: Agree. Voting to reopen. It is useful to recognize that some authors are imprecise but not all are. Clarity in the use of these terms deserves support.

Comment: You are right -- your two answers are convincing evidence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose we have:

```
f <- function(x) x + 1
comment(f) <- "my function"
f(3)
```

**Arguments**  We distinguish between *formal arguments* and *actual arguments*. In the above `x` is the *formal argument* to `f`.  The names of the formal arguments of `f` are given by:

```
> names(formals(f))
[1] "x"
```

The *actual arguments* to a function vary from one call to another and in the above example there is a single actual argument `3`.

The function `args` can be used to display the entire function signature of a function including the formal arguments and the default arguments and if you are debugging a function you can enter `match.call()` to list the function signature with the actual arguments substituted.

**Attributes** The *attributes* of an R object are given by `attributes(f)` like this:

```
> attributes(f)
$srcref
function(x) x + 1

$comment
[1] "my function"
```

There is one exception and that is that an object's *class* is also regarded as an attribute but is not given by the above but rather is given by `class`:

```
> class(f)
[1] "function"
```

**Parameters**   Sometimes function arguments are referred to as *parameters* or sometimes one refers to those arguments which are fixed as parameters but this tends to be related more to mathematics and statistics than R.

In statistical models the model is typically a function of the data and the *model parameters* often via the likelihood. For example, here:

```
> lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)

Call:
lm(formula = demand ~ Time, data = BOD)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Time  
      8.521        1.721
```

the linear regression coefficients of Intercept and Time (viz. 8.521 and 1.721) are often referred to as model parameters.

As Dwin has already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463851/confused-about-r-terminology-attributes-parameters-and-arguments/15464247#15464247) the various values influencing graphics in R are also termed parameters and can be displayed via:

```
> par()
```

and the corresponding concepts in other R graphics systems are often also referred to as parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and conclusive explanation. I am quite new to R and find the terminology in the R literature somewhat confusing. For example, in "R in Action", Kabacoff uses the word "options" for the "arguments" of plot functions.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose colloquial use of the term "attribute" might refer to several features of data objects, but there is a very specific meaning in R. An attribute is a value returned by either the functions: `attributes` or `attr`. These are critical to the language in that classes and names are stored as attributes. There two other assignment functions: `attributes<-` and `attr<-` that allow additional attributes to be assigned in support of class specific objectives.

```
?attributes
?attr
```

There is a `par` function which sets graphical "parameters" that control the base graphics behavior. So that would be an R-specific use of parameter than might be slightly different than use of "argument" which is generally applied to the formal arguments to functions.

```
?par
```

The is a function `args` which applied to a function name or an anonymous function will return its arguments (as a "closure" which gets printed on the console just as a user would type during a function definition) along with their default values. The function `formals` will return the same "argument"  information in the form of a list.

```
?args
?formals
```

I realize I am implicitly arguing with Matthew whose R skills are excellent. Contrary to him, I think that `attributes`  and `arguments` have more specific meanings in the context of R and that careful authors will make an effort to keep their meanings separate. I would not have a problem understanding someone who uses `parameter` as a synonym for argument if the context were clearly a discussion of applying a function, since that is the typical parlance in mathematics. I would agree with the conclusion of your last sentence. Those are 'arguments' and most emphatically not attributes. The attributes of an object returned by heatmap are:

```
 > attributes(hv)  #from first example in ?heatmap
 #$names
 # [1] "rowInd" "colInd" "Rowv"   "Colv"
```

But only  some of the arguments became attributes and then only after being assigned to the returned value during the function execution.

Comment: +1The question is maybe not constructive but this answer is really constructive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how analogous R is to Python, but I think most of the terms should be consistent across different languages. From what I read and learned in the last couple of days, a **parameter** is basically what a function takes as its input **when you define it**:

```
my_function <- function (param1, param2){
...
}
```

and it is called **argument** if you are invoking a function with certain input values (that are passed to the function as parameters):

```
my_function(arg1, arg2)
```

Functions that are part of a class are called **method**. And an **attribute** can be either a value or method associated with a class object (or so-called **instance**)

So the question whether we call something argument or attribute depends on what we are calling: a function or a method. But I would say now **argument** is an appropriate term if we call the `heatmap` function, for example:

```
heatmap(my_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Attribute** : Object's properties, e.g. Person has **String fName, lName;**

**Parameter**: appears in function/method definition e.g. public void setName(**fName**, **lName**)

**Argument**:  value passed for a method/function's parameter when invoking/calling the method/function e.g. myPerson.setName("**Michael**", "**Jackson"**)